# Jmeter: How to use all variables of the array in one HTTP request?

Tags: jmeter

I have basic knowledge in Jmeter tool. I have an array of veriables, which I get using Regular Expression Extractor. Then I need use each variables in one HTTP request. If I use ForEach Controller I get dublicate requests.

How can I to use all variables of the array in one HTTP request?

Many Thanks

Comment: The foreach will iterate the array and give duplicates requests if it is using the same array index each time. How did you configure the Foreach controller to get duplicates?
Not sure what problem you want solving, using each variable in a unique request (no duplicates), or using all variables in one single request? Clarify the question and I can answer for you.

Comment: I need to use all variables in one single request. And I solved my problem. I added debug sampler and saw the index of each element in array. Then I set variable with the index in my request: ${MyVar_N}, ${MyVar_N+1}, ...

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can also use in a loop with ${MyVar_MatchNr} as the size of the 'list'